# About simple connectedness

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, homology-cohomology

Two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$ are homotopic if there exists continuous $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $Id_Y$ and $g\circ f $ homotopic to $Id_X$ (regardless any embedding of $X$ and $Y$ in a bigger topological space). This leads to the definition of a simply connected space; a space where any two loops are homotopic and I am confused:

1- Any two circles are homotopic (because they are diffeomorphic), So what means non homotopic circles on the torus $T^2$? hence my problem: is a homotopy a relative concept?

2- If I take as a definition of the simple connectedness of a manifold $M$, the vanishing of its de Rham cohomology space $H^1(M)=0$. One can easily show that the sphere $S^2$ is simply connected. 
By Stereographic projections by $S^2=U\cup V$ with $U$ and $V$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (thus contractible) and $U\cap V$ is homotopic to the circle $S^1$. Using the long exact sequence of Mayer-Vietoris:
$$ 0\to H^0(S^2)\to H^0(U)\oplus H^0(V)\to H^0(U\cap V)\to H^1(S^2)\to 0$$
so $1-2+1-\dim H^1(S^2)=0$.

How to show that two loops in $S^2$ are homotopic using the fact that $H^1(S^2)=0$? I know that if a $1$-differential form is exact then its integral over all loop is zero. Is the converse true?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Homotopy is usually applied to maps, not to spaces. In homotopic topology, a “circle on *X*” is understood as a map from S¹ to *X*.

Comment: The property you wrote down (there exist continuous maps $f: X \to Y$ and $g: Y\to X$ such that $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $\operatorname{Id}_Y$ and $g\circ f $ homotopic to $\operatorname{Id}_X$) is what it means to say that $X$ and $Y$ are _homotopy equivalent_, not homotopic.

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to show that $S^2$ is simply-connected just using $H^1_{\operatorname{dR}}(S^2)=0$? The only arguments I'm familiar with use facts (e.g. that simple-connectedness is equivalent to $H^1=0$ for finite polyhedra in $S^3$) that are far more powerful than, say, van Kampen's theorem or basic facts about CW complexes (which can easily show that $S^2$ is simply-connected).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to echo Incnis Mrsi's comment: The first concept you describe is called *homotopy equivalence* of spaces. Two spaces are then homotopy equivalent if there are compositions of continuous maps $X \overset{f}{\to} Y \overset{g}{\to} X$ homotopic to $\operatorname{id}_X$ and $Y \overset{g}{\to} X \overset{f}{\to} Y$ homotopic to $\operatorname{id}_Y$. As for your specific questions:

**1.** When we say "a circle in the torus $T^2$", we usually mean a continuous map $f: S^1 \to T^2$. Two homotopic circles in the torus are then two continuous maps $f,g:S^1 \to T^2$ such that there is another continuous map $F : S^1 \times [0,1] \to T^2$ with $F_0=f$ and $F_1=g$. The subspaces $f(S^1)\subset T^2$ and $g(S^1)\subset T^2$ may not be homotopy equivalent even if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic, and vice versa. For example, all loops $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ are homotopic to the constant map $f: S^1 \to \{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible. But the unit circle $S^1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is certainly not homotopy equivalent to the origin $\{0\} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

**2.** While it is true that a manifold $M$ that is simply-connected in the standard sense, i.e. in which all loops $S^1 \to M$ are homotopic, will have $H^1 _{\operatorname{dR}}(M)=0$, the converse is false. There are non-simply-connected manifolds whose first de Rham cohomology groups are zero. For example, if you know about (singular) (co)homology with coefficients (which I'll denote by $H_*$ and $H^*$), you can use $$H^1_{\operatorname{dR}}(M) \cong H^1(M;\mathbb{R}) \cong H^1(M;\mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R} \cong \operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(H_1(M;\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{R})$$ to compute $H^1_{\operatorname{dR}}(\mathbb{RP}^3)\cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\otimes \mathbb{R}=0$. But $\pi_1(\mathbb{RP}^3)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \neq 0$, so $\mathbb{RP}^3$ is not simply-connected.

**Update:** In your comment below, you asked if the map $\varphi: H^1(M) \to \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(M),(\mathbb{R},+))$ defined by $(\varphi(\omega))(\gamma)=\int_\gamma \omega$ is an isomorphism. The answer is *yes* (at least for compact manifolds), but you may not yet have learned the tools necessary to see this.  To see that it is injective, we'll show that the kernel is trivial: Suppose $(\varphi(\omega))(\gamma)=\int_\gamma \omega=0$ for all $\gamma: S^1 \to M$. This implies that $\omega$ is an exact form $df$, where $f$ can be constructed by setting $f(x_0)=0$ for some chosen $x_0 \in M$ and then letting $f(x)=\int_c \omega$ where $c$ is any curve from $x_0$ to $x$. Thus $[\omega]=0$ in $H^1(M)$, and $\varphi$ is injective. 
A proof of surjectivity would probably require tools that you have not yet learned,
such as the fact that singular homology $H_1(M;\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the abelianization of $\pi_1(M)$, i.e. the quotient $\pi_1(M)/[\pi_1(M),\pi_1(M)]$ where $[\pi_1(M),\pi_1(M)]$ is the "commutator subgroup" generated by elements like $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$.

Unfortunately, this isomorphism might not help prove $\pi_1(S^2)=0$. This is because a nontrivial group $G\neq 0$ can have $\operatorname{Hom}(G,(\mathbb{R},+))=0$, such as $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. If you can show that $\pi_1(S^2)$ is abelian and torsion-free, then $\operatorname{Hom}(\pi_1(S^2),(\mathbb{R},+))\cong H^1(S^2)=0$ will imply $\pi_1(S^2)=0$, but this is *way* harder than showing $\pi_1(S^2)=0$ directly.

Comment: @ squirrel: Many thanks for your nice answer, the terminology is now clear. I am not familiar with singular (co)homology with coefficients. I use only the fact that forms on the projective space are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2$-invariant forms on the sphere to show that $H^k(\mathbb{RP}^n)\simeq\left(H^k(S^n)\right)^{\mathbb{Z}_2}=0$ for $n\geq2$. How to prove $\pi_1(M)=0\longrightarrow H_{dR}^1(M)=0$ ? the map $\varphi : \omega\mapsto\left(\gamma\to\int_\gamma \omega\right)$, from $H^1(M)$ to $\{homomorphisms : \pi_1(M)\to(\mathbb{R},+)\}$ is it an isomorphism?

Comment: @user56980: Just updated the post in response to your comment.

Comment: Many thans squirrel! Yes, if $G$ is a finite group than $\operatorname{Hom}(G,(\mathbb{R},+))=0$. I'm bad in group theory (free groups, amalgamated product ...) but I can use a result (from Van Kampen) which states that the union of two simply connected, whose intersection is path connected is simply connected. May I ask you some references for group theory necessary for singular homology and references for cohomology with coefficients. Thanks!

Comment: @user56980: Indeed, the argument you mentioned, namely applying Van Kampen's theorem to the decomposition $S^2 = (S^2 \setminus \{\text{north pole}\}) \cup (S^2 \setminus \{\text{south pole}\}$, is the easiest way to prove $\pi_1(S^2)=0$. I think most people would recommend *Algebraic Topology* by Allen Hatcher (freely available online). Hatcher covers free groups and amalgamated products in Chapter 1, where he discusses the fundamental group and covering space theory.

Comment: That's great, thanks a lot squirrel!